# How to find functions with same reference address in typescript AST

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

example:

```js
import { method } from 'lib'

const a = method
const b = a
const c = method
// a b c is the same function
```

In AST, I can get the variable name `method` from ImportDeclaration,

but how can I find `a` `b` `c` ?

My purpose is to record where `method` has called